# How to change content of an image lying in a different frame onmouseover of another image?

Tags: javascript, html, location, frame, onmouseover

I'm learning and couldn't come across a solution by searching.

This is what I used when I had to hover over an item (e.g., image) to change to content of another item (e.g., iframe). **THIS worked**...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
  <img href="#" src="FirstImage.jpg" alt="Hover to reveal second Image"
      onmouseover="IFRAME.location='SecondImage.jpg'"
      onmouseout="IFRAME.location='text.html'"/>

</div>
<div>
<iframe name="IFRAME" src="text.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**BUT WHAT** do I need to do if the second item is in a different frame (i.e., 1st item is in one frame, 2nd in another)? Because it won't detect the 'name="IFRAME"' value which is in a different frame.

I tried experimenting with

`onmouseover="parent.frames[1].IFRAME.location="SecondImage.jpg"`

but couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. add jQuery link
2. add id for image and iframe
3. add script block (below)

I made working sample: http://jsbin.com/acocil/4/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <img id="image1" href="#" src="FirstImage.jpg" alt="Hover to reveal second Image"/>
</div>
<div>
<iframe id="frame1" name="IFRAME" src="text.html"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#image1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#frame1').attr('src','SecondImage.jpg');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#frame1').attr('src','text.html');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and for two frames:

```
<iframe id="frame1" alt="Hover to reveal second Image"></iframe>  
<iframe id="frame2" src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></iframe> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frame1')[0].contentDocument.write('<img id="image1" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/msg/site/9/sp/ic_biggrin.gif"/>');
  $('#frame1').contents().find('img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#frame2').attr('src','https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#frame2').attr('src','http://lostfilm.tv');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is this works with the id (as it worked in the code in my question) only for the same page. But what if the location of the first image in one frame of a frameset and the iframe is in another frame? How do you associate them with each other?

<html>
<head></head>
<frameset rows=50,50>
<frame src="THISCONTAINSTHEIMAGE.html">
<frame src="THISCONTAINSTHEIFRAME.html">
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: <iframe id="frame1" alt="Hover to reveal second Image"></iframe>  
<iframe id="frame2" src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></iframe> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frame1')[0].contentDocument.write('<img id="image1" src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/msg/site/9/sp/ic_biggrin.gif"/>');
  $('#frame1').contents().find('img').mouseover(function(){
    $('#frame2').attr('src','https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#frame2').attr('src','http://lostfilm.tv');
  });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an ID to the IFRAME, then use 'document.getElementById' to refer the ID in onmouseover event.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
  <img href="#" src="FirstImage.jpg" alt="Hover to reveal second Image"
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('myid').src='SecondImage.jpg'"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('myid').src='text.html'"/>

</div>
<div>
<iframe id="myid" name="IFRAME" src="text.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing is this works with the id (as it worked in the code in my question) only for the same page. But what if the location of the first image in one frame of a frameset and the iframe is in another frame? How do you associate them with each other? <html> <head></head> <frameset rows=50,50> <frame src="THISCONTAINSTHEIMAGE.html"> <frame src="THISCONTAINSTHEIFRAME.html"> </frameset> </html>

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot reference the IFRAME using "parent." then you can put a javascript function in the "parent" frame which will do what you want to the IFRAME and call it from the internal iframe :
    parent.changeImage('myid');

So this function could be in the parent :

```
function changeImage(theID);(){
    document.getElementById(theID).src='SecondImage.jpg';
}
```